# generating with angularJS HTML from JSON-Objects

Tags: json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm developing an app with the Ionic framework based on angularjs. I'd like to let generate HTML elements or components from a JSON file. These are buttons, lists, labels, etc.

My JSON objects look like this:

```
[
  {
    "category": "communicationPage",
    "type": "Button",
    "id": "communicationButton",
    "icon": "ion-chatboxes",
    "name": "Communication",
    "onClick": "window.location.href='communicationPage.html'",
    "ngclick": "open()",
    "ngcontroller": "openctrl",
    "color": "white",
    "background-color": "#ff5db1",
    "font-size": "20px"
  },
  {
    "category": "servicePage",
    "type": "Button",
    "id": "serviceButton",
    "icon": "ion-briefcase",
    "name": "Service",
    "onClick": "window.location.href='servicePage.html'",
    "color": "blue",
    "background-color": "#009900",
    "font-size": "26px"
  }
]
```

I can access via my Controller on the JSON file and parse as follows:

```
myApp.controller('generateHTMLCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('myJSONFile.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.components = data;
        //...
    });
});
```

The code translates of course nothing.

1. My question is, how can I adapt my JavaScript code so that from a
   JSON object following HTML element is generated?:

`<button style="color: blue; background-color: #ff5db1; font-size: 20px" onclick="window.location.href='communicationPage.html'" id="communicationButton" class="button">
<i class="ion-chatboxes"></i> <br> Communication
</button>`

Once my JSON object is located always in the JSON file, should always be created the HTML element on the page.

2. The second question is how I can position this generated HTML
   element just in my HTML page?

I want that the HTML element is generated between the responsive grid element, such as:

```
 <div class="row responsive-sm">
    <div class="col">
      <!-- The Button should be generated hier-->
    </div>
 </div>
```

3. The third and final question is how I can let generate the HTML
   element on the appropriate page? Such as: If in JSON object the key-value pair of `"category": "communicationPage"` occurs should the corresponding HTML element be created on `'communicationPage.html'`

I would look forward to an example. Many thanks.

Comment: why would you use `<button>` for redirect and not use an `<a>` tag with an href? Question #3 is very unclear what you are asking

Comment: You're right. But what is better in this case by using `<a></a>` and what worse  by using `<button></button>`?

Comment: semantics and accessibility. Still not clear what you are trying to do either

Comment: For Question # 3: Is it possible that I can automatically generate the HTML elements from a JSON object on a targeted certain page? When key-value pair `"category": "communicationPage"` is in my JSON object located this button automatically should be generated on the HTML page named`communicationPage.html`. I want to work only in my JSON file not with the HTML-Code in html.page. So I would like to add the HTML elements on my page or delete from my page by editing the JSON-File. So the components should be deleted or added on the targeted page.

Comment: It appears you are leaving your angular single page application and loading different pages from server. You would need to use url query parameters or localStorage to provide data for other pages. The other page would know nothing about your angular application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the two first point, use the `data-binding` and `ng-repeat` :  directive

```
<div class="row reponsive-sm" ng-controller="generateHTMLCtrl">
     <div ng-repeat="component in components">
       <button style="color : {{component.color}}; background-color : {{component.background-color}} ... ">
       </button>
     </div>
</div>
```

For the last point, I'm not sure if it's possible with AngularJS ...

Comment: can you maybe give an example how I use expression for `ng-controller` and  `ng-click` tags from a json object. Like `ng-click"{{component.ngclick}}"` and `ng-controller"{{component.ngcontroller}}"`. If I use the expression so I get error